# What is the probability that $x$ will not work due to failure rate $0.0111$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I've tried using the probability mass function for binomial distribution in this case but it seems to not be the appropriate approach unless I calculated wrong. How am I supposed to approach this problem?

Here is the actual question:

A device has $35$ integrated circuits. The probability that any integrated circuit is defective is $0.0111$, and the integrated circuits are independent. The product operates only if there are no defective integrated circuits. What is the probability that the product operates?

I tried using binomial pdf. 35 as the amount of circuits, 0.0111 as the probability, and 1 as the chance of being defective. Would I need to calculate it based off 35 being defective? Since that's when the product would not work?

Comment: The probability an individual IC is good is $1-0.0111$. What is the probability all $35$ are good?

Comment: Forget about binomial "pdf" etc which will serve only to confuse you even more and proceed as follows. What is the probability that circuit #1 is in _working condition?_ What is the probability that _both_ circuits #1 and #2 are in working condition? (Subhint: that word _independent_ might be helpful here) Lather, rinse, repeat till you get the probability that circuits #1, #2, #3, ... $35 are all in working condition.

Comment: I took the amount of circuits, asked what the probability that they would _be successful_ for one and then used that to find out the probability that all of them would be successful. Thanks for the hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be the random variable that takes the values $0,1,...35$ and represents the number of defective circuits. Compute $\mathbb P(X=0)$ given that $\mathbb P(X=x)=\binom{35}{x}p^x(1-p)^{35}$. Why are you taking $1$ as the chance of being defective? The probability that the product operates is the probability that none of the circuits are defective.